# My facebook login dialog is popped UNDER my current modal view. What to do now?

Tags: iphone, view, facebook, dialog, modal-dialog

Any similar experiences (I'm on iPad)?

Comment: Why did you give your user the chance to press "login" while in another modal view? Is the login button INSIDE the modal view that causes the trouble?

Comment: If user runs the App first, then press share, he/she hasn't connected to facebook. This is the case when facebook login should pop up (while share ViewController is presented modally). On iPad its more common to present views modal instead of a fullscreen transistion. Suggestions (other than forget about it)?

Answer (score 0):

It depends where you present your modal view controller from.
If your root controller is already presenting a modal view and you show another one, it will be shown under the open modal view.
The solution is to present the 2nd modal controller from the one that is already open.
But nevertheless I think it is not a good design (at least on iOS) to have two or more modals stacked.